# Limit user requests in Laravel application

Tags: php, laravel-4, httprequest

I am building an application using Laravel. I need to limit the number of requests a user can make to the server. I mean of the user is making too many requests too quickly. I think this must be a standard problem and there must be some kind of package to handle and limit requests? Or if somebody can provide a simple solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Request limitation is better done on the web server (Apache) side.

Here are some solutions:

- [mod_evasive](http://www.zdziarski.com/blog/?page_id=442) (Focused more on reducing DoS exposure)
- [mod_cband](http://dembol.org/blog/mod_cband/) (Best featured for 'normal' bandwidth control)

and the rest

- [mod_limitipconn](http://dominia.org/djao/limitipconn.html)
- [mod_bw](http://bwmod.sourceforge.net/)
- [mod_bwshare](http://www.topology.org/src/bwshare/README.html)